# Python Array Reshaping Issue to Array with Shape (None, 192)

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I have this error and I'm not sure how do I reshape where there's a dimension with `None`.

```
Exception: Error when checking : expected input_1 to have shape (None, 192) but got array with shape (192, 1)
```

How do I reshape an array to (None, 192)?

I've the array `accuracy` with shape `(12, 16)` and I did `accuracy.reshape(-1)` that gives `(192,)`. However this is not `(None, 192)`.

Comment: `arr.ravel()[None]` or `arr.reshape(1,-1)`?

Comment: [Suspiciously similar](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3109)

Comment: @AndrasDeak Thanks for the link!

Comment: So you need to tell us which module(s) you are running.  Apparently this is not occurring in `numpy` itself.  I'd expect the error to be, `expected (1,192) got ...`; `None` (`np.newaxis`) is used to create a a size `1` dimension, but you won't see it in a `shape` tuple or error message.  But a module in early stages of development might still use it.

Answer (score 0):

In `keras/keras/engine/training.py`

```
def standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes=None,
                           check_batch_dim=True,
                           exception_prefix=''):
     ...

    # check shapes compatibility
    if shapes:
        for i in range(len(names)):
        ...
        for j, (dim, ref_dim) in enumerate(zip(array.shape, shapes[i])):
            if not j and not check_batch_dim:
                # skip the first axis
                continue
            if ref_dim:
                if ref_dim != dim:
                    raise Exception('Error when checking ' + exception_prefix +
                                    ': expected ' + names[i] +
                                    ' to have shape ' + str(shapes[i]) +
                                    ' but got array with shape ' +
                                    str(array.shape))
```

Comparing that with the error

```
Error when checking : expected input_1 to have shape (None, 192) but got array with shape (192, 1)
```

So it is comparing `(None, 192)` with `(192, 1)`, and skipping the 1st axis; that is comparing `192` and `1`.  If `array` has shape `(n, 192)` it probably would pass.

So basically, what ever is generating the `(192,1)` shape, as opposed to `(1,192)` or a broadcastable `(192,)` is causing the error.

I'm adding `keras` to the tags on the guess that this is the problem module.

Searching other `keras` tagged SO questions:

[Exception: Error when checking model target: expected dense_3 to have shape (None, 1000) but got array with shape (32, 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39335434/exception-error-when-checking-model-target-expected-dense-3-to-have-shape-non)

[Error: Error when checking model input: expected dense_input_6 to have shape (None, 784) but got array with shape (784L, 1L)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37901698/error-error-when-checking-model-input-expected-dense-input-6-to-have-shape-no)

[Dimensions not matching in keras LSTM model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40088381/dimensions-not-matching-in-keras-lstm-model)

[Getting shape dimension errors with a simple regression using Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39308273/getting-shape-dimension-errors-with-a-simple-regression-using-keras)

[Deep autoencoder in Keras converting one dimension to another i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39976718/deep-autoencoder-in-keras-converting-one-dimension-to-another-i)

I don't know enough about `keras` to understand the answers, but there's more to it than simply reshaping your input array.